# Fetch more than 100,000 records in Redshift

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I have a requirement to fetch more than 400,000 records from Redshift and export it to Excel. But in Redshift, maximum limit is 100,000. So I am unable to fetch records in one go to Excel.

Please help me with this, how I can do this.

Note:- I am using Aginity Workbench for Redshift for querying data.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a limitation of your **SQL tool**.

Instead, you could use the Redshift [UNLOAD - Amazon Redshift](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_UNLOAD.html) command to run a query and save the results to Amazon S3. You can then download the results from S3.

This can result in multiple files. If you only want a single file, use the option `PARALLEL OFF`.